# Join a superset table with subset

Tags: sql-server, join

I am on MSSQL. I have two tables. One has ID and row values:

**ID**

```
1

2

3

4

5
```

Another table has ID and Amount

**ID, Amount**

```
3, 30

4, 40

5, 50
```

I want a query that will give me:

**ID, Amount**

```
1, 0

2, 0

3, 30

4, 40

5, 50
```

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then, assuming the tables names are TableA and TableB, you could use a left outer join, like so:

```
SELECT A.ID, ISNULL(B.Amount, 0) Amount
  FROM TableA A
 LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB B
   ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Using left outer join will return all rows from the first table (TableA) while the ISNULL(B.Amount, 0) function will return 0 for those rows returned that have a NULL Amount (i.e. for those rows in TableA that do not have a corresponding row with the same ID in TableB).